# Run JAR which will trigger Chrome driver from PHP

Tags: java, php, eclipse, google-chrome, jar

I have written a JAVA program which will trigger Chrome driver and open google.com the program works fine in eclipse so I created a JAR file.
Even the JAR file is working fine independently. It will open google.com in google chrome then its closing the chrome driver.
But I am trying to trigger this JAR through PHP now for some reason this is not working.

The PHP is not triggering the JAR file at all.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Chrome_Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Telling the system where to find the Chrome driver
        System.getProperty("user.dir" + "\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        // Open google.com
        webDriver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
        // Printing result here.
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);
        webDriver.close();
        webDriver.quit();

    }

}
```

My PHP Code:

```
<?php

exec("java -jar TEST10.jar");

?>
```

TEST10 is the name of the JAR containing the above Java program.

Comment: If it's your PHP code that isn't working, that's what you need to post.

Comment: in php you could use the native executable function : exec  http://php.net/manual/fr/function.exec.php with a command like ```java -jar myjar.jar``` but this is really ugly... what are you trying to achieve??

Comment: Sorry my bad, forgot to add PHP code. Added now